# How to maintain same Correlation id's after using Splitter and few other Components?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration XPath Splitters and Header Enrichers as below:

```
    <!-- split the folders-->
    <int-xml:xpath-splitter input-channel="PQAdditionalContactHistory-Split-Filtered-Folders-Channel" output-channel="PQAdditionalContactHistory-Split-Filtered-Folders-Channel" >
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//response/results/PQCallHistory/row"/>
    </int-xml:xpath-splitter>

<int:chain  input-channel="PQAdditionalContactHistory-Split-Filtered-Folders-Channel" output-channel="PQContactHistory-InputChannel" >
    <int:service-activator  ref="msgHandler" method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" />
    <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQAdditionalContactHistory-To-PQContactHistory-Request}" />
</int:chain>   

<int:channel id="PQContactHistory-InputChannel" />              
    <int:chain input-channel="PQContactHistory-InputChannel" output-channel="PQContactHistory-OutputChannel">

        <int-xml:xpath-splitter>
            <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//PQCallHistory"  namespace-map="xmlMessageNamespace" />
        </int-xml:xpath-splitter>

        <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQContactHistoryStoredProcData}"  />

        <!-- Store the original payload in header for future purpose -->
        <int:header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
            <int:header name="${headerNames.originalPayload}" expression="payload" />   
        </int:header-enricher>  
    </int:chain>
```

Here, the plan is to use an aggregator and combine all the split messages after performing some operations using those split messages. The surprise here is all the list of split messages are not arriving at the aggregator at once. When I investigated further to know the root cause, I found that the correlation id's of the split messages are changed after second splitter. But, I need all the list of messages split by first splitter arriving as one chunk at the aggregator end. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Please let me know if my question is not clear.

I am using default `<aggregator>` behaviour:`<int:aggregator input-channel="test" ref="xmlAggregator" method="aggreagateAdditionalFolders"></int:aggregator>`.

Answer (score 1):

That's truth, because any `splitter` provides `SequenceDetails`(`sequenceId`, `sequenceSize` etc) by default within its scope and stores them in the `MessageHeaders` via `stack` manner.

Unfortunately the `<int-xml:xpath-splitter>` [doesn't support](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1188) `apply-sequence="false"` yet.

But you can follow with JIRA workaround for that Pull Request.

That's only one side for overcoming your use-case.

Another matter is around the `<aggregator>`. There is need to know how you `correlate` and `release` group there.

I may guess you just rely on default `<aggregator>` behaviour - getting deal with that `SequenceDetails` headers.

That's not good. After the first `xpath-splitter`, the `sequenceSize` header has gotten the value as a number of reply messages. Since you are going to `split` each of them one more time, there is no info how much items will come to the `<aggregator>`.

The same is about a `sequenceNumber` header, which means a marker for `<aggregator>` to apply the message to the goup or not.

So, show, please, your aggregator configuration. And after that we'll try to provide the solution together.

Anyway in this case you should provide some custom `ReleaseStrategy` for aggregator.
The `CorrelationStrategy` may remain as default one.

**UPDATE**

The sample how to configure `XPathMessageSplitter` as a generic bean:

```
<int:service-activator>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.xml.splitter.XPathMessageSplitter">
        <beans:constructor-arg type="org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpression">
            <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//PQCallHistory" namespace-map="xmlMessageNamespace" />
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

Comment: Thanks Artem for your response.I am glad to see you on SO.Just I am using default <aggregator> behaviour:<int:aggregator  input-channel="test4" ref="xmlAggregator"  method="aggreagateAdditionalFolders"></int:aggregator>. The problem here is I am using many Xpath splitters in the code, but I just need the aggregation of the messages split by the first splitter. However   I am able to get the split messages of the first splitter in different lists of messages. But, Ideally, they should arrive as a single list of messages at the aggregator end. It would be great if you can share some pseudo code.

Comment: Glad to see you, too! Would be better, if you move your code and this comment to the question to make it more readable and consistent. And there is need to understand, what is the reason to aggregate nested spitted messages as root onces...

Comment: I moved the code to question.I am not aggragating the nested messages as root message. I use many splitters in my code to just enrich the response and for other purposes.So, ultimately, in my code, the number of splitters is not equal to the number of aggregators. I just want to combine the split messageo of the first splitter. Of course, the split messages are modified in the middle till they reach the aggregator. But I am expecting all of them coming as one list of messages.For eg: Assume first splitter yielded 2 messages. Then aggregator should receive those two messages as single list.

Comment: If you want to ignore nested splitted messages it just enough to configure `XPathMessageSplitter` as I've shown in JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3415. The main trick - disable `apply-sequence` for nested splitters.

Comment: However, you say you want the transformed results of the second splitter to arrive as a "List" at your aggregator. To achieve that, simply add a second aggregator - it will use the information from the second splitter to aggregate to a `Collection` and "pop" the previous correlation info. That's the way it's designed to work.

Comment: Artem,I will try the approach suggested by you and let you know tomorrow. Thanks much for your assistance.

Comment: Gary, I need the transformed results of the first splitter as a "List" at the aggregator. But the messages are not arriving as a "List" since the corerelation id's are changed due to the second splitter in the middle.

Comment: Artem,I have configured the splitter exactly as you mentioned in the JIRA item https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3415. But, strangely,the splitter is not even splitting the message. I have configured as: <int:splitter>
      <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="#xpath(payload, '//PQCallHistory')"  namespace-map="xmlMessageNamespace" />
</int:splitter>. Earlier <int-xml:xpath-splitter> was splitting the message without any issues.But now <int:splitter> is failing to split the message.Am I doing any thing wrong?

Comment: No, it should be simple `expression="#xpath(payload, '//PQCallHistory')"`, not, `<int-xml:xpath-expression>` sub-element. However, since you use `namespace-map` I think there is no other choice, unless configuration of `XPathMessageSplitter` genric bean. `#xpath()` SpEL-function doesn't support namespaces.

Comment: Artem,You mean to say do I need to customize XPathMessageSplitter? If so could you please add some pseudo code to the answer?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You just need to add `<bean>` for that class as main concern here is `applySequence = false`. And use it as a `ref` from `<service-activator>`

Comment: Added sample to the answer.

Comment: @Artem,Sorry for late reply. I was OOTO all these days.I tried with the code `<int:service-activator>
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.xml.splitter.XPathMessageSplitter">
        <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathExpression">
            <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="#xpath(payload, '//PQCallHistory')" namespace-map="xmlMessageNamespace" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>`. But I am getting the exception `Could not find function: #xpath`.Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You should use Spring Integration 3.0 or above and have `spring-integration-xml.jar` in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @Artem,thanks for quick response.I am using spring-integration-core: 3.0.1 jar. The `expression="#xpath......` was working fine for couple of my earlier completed tasks.But this time it is not working for this task.I suspect that there is something wrong with the configuration.Could you please verify my configuration once?

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I wasn't right with `<xpath-expression>` definition. Edited my answer.

Comment: @Artem,This time `expression="#xpath......` is working. But again the same initial aggregation problem exists .i.e. the split messages are not coming as a "List" of messages.

Comment: @Artem, It appears that still the Correlation Id's are changed after the second split operation.

Comment: True, because the general purpose of that code is to set `applySequence = false` for the `XPathMessageSplitter`.

Comment: @Artem,is there any workaround to maintain the correlation id's as same after second split? Or at least, is there any other workaround to get the messages as a "List" at the aggregator's end?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. The aggregator returs `List` by default. Why `applySequence = false` isn't enough for you ?

Comment: @Artem, Yeah.The aggregator returns `List` by default. In my case the aggregator is returning a separate `List` for each split message.For example, Assume the message is split into two parts with the first splitter.Then naturally, I will expect those two messages coming in a single `List` at the aggregator's end rather than each split message in a separate `List`. But, in reality, these two messages are coming in two different `Lists` at the aggregator'e end.

Comment: @Artem, The reason is after the second split operation the correlation id's of the already split messages by the first splitter  are changed.So, they are coming as two different `Lists` at aggragtor's end. I mean the aggregator is not able to identify the split messages properly. Please let me know if it is not clear. I appreciate your support.

Comment: Or you should use an `<aggregtor>` for each nested splitter, or just use `applySequence = false` as I suggested. But in the last case you should be sure what to do with all those nested messages.